# support for recording events in a .net application

Tags: .net, events, macros, recording

I need help on how to implement support for recording user events in a .net  application just like macro in office. SO if the user records his actions, all the things he performed will be re executed.

Some other apps like Notepadd++ has this feature too, i don't know if this is possible in .net

thanks

EDIT
I saw this article in code project [Writing a Macro Recorder/Player using Win32 Journal Hooks](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/winmacro.aspx) that does hooking to mouse and keybord, how does one do that in .net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've implemented that in one of my applications.

I used a [command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) in my architecture. The record button in the application sets a RecordingFlag.
While the RecordingFlag is true, store all the executed commands (read Command pattern first to understand this) until RecordingFlag is false (user push record button again).

Running the recorded macro is just iterate the stored commands and execute them in order.

Comment: is it possible to see your app?

Comment: I'm sorry but it was years ago in another job. I haven't example code.